# Best way to calculate the free space using statvfs structure?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel

whether we have to use

1. f_bfree × f_frsize
      or
2. f_bfree × f_bsize

to calculate the free disk space in a file system

```
struct statvfs {
    unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* file system block size */
    unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* fragment size */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* size of fs in f_frsize units */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* # free blocks */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bavail;   /* # free blocks for unprivileged users */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_files;    /* # inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_ffree;    /* # free inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_favail;   /* # free inodes for unprivileged users */
    unsigned long  f_fsid;     /* file system ID */
    unsigned long  f_flag;     /* mount flags */
    unsigned long  f_namemax;  /* maximum filename length */
};
```

Comment: I believe that it is option 2 (f_bsize).  f_bfree is the number of free ***blocks***, so you should multiply it by the size of a block.

Comment: Note that the output of df shows f_bavail*f_bsize as the available space.